# Populate additional column by comparing 3 rows of same Id and get distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table **DayCnt**

```
create table DayCnt (
    Id int not null,
    StatusType varchar(255),
    SentDate date,
    DaysTakenToReach int
);

create unique clustered index uci on DayCnt (Id, StatusType);
```

With these values:

```
insert into DayCnt values ('1', 'Delivered','02/22/2020',3)
insert into DayCnt values ('1', 'Receipt','02/25/2020',null)
insert into DayCnt values ('1', 'Consent','02/22/2020',null)
insert into DayCnt values ('22', 'Delivered','03/28/2020',1)
insert into DayCnt values ('22', 'Receipt','03/29/2020',null)
insert into DayCnt values ('22', 'Consent','03/28/2020',null)
insert into DayCnt values ('333', 'Delivered','04/28/2020',1)
insert into DayCnt values ('333', 'Receipt','04/29/2020',null)
insert into DayCnt values ('333', 'Consent',null,null)
```

I want to update its **StatusType** and add in a **DeliveryMethod** cloumn and populate it depending on these 3 conditions:

- *If DaysTakenToReach are 3 or more days apart then 'USPS'*
- *If DaysTakenToReach are 2 or fewer days apart and the StatusType = 'Consent' contains a date for that Id then 'E-Delivery'*
- *If DaysTakenToReach are 2 or fewer days apart and the StatusType = 'Consent' contains a null in the date column for that Id then 'In Person'*

I'm trying this with the following code:

```
select
    Id, 
    NewStatusType = 'DONE',
    DeliveryMethod = case 
                        when DaysTakenToReach >= 3 then 'USPS' 
                        when DaysTakenToReach < 3 then case when StatusType = 'Consent' and SentDate is not null then 'E-Delivery' end
                        when DaysTakenToReach < 3 then case when StatusType = 'Consent' and SentDate is null then 'In Person' end
                     end 
into #New
from DayCnt
```

But my case expressions for the 2nd and 3rd condition seems off.
I'm expecting something like this:

```
Id          NewStatusType DeliveryMethod
----------- ------------- --------------
1           DONE          USPS
22          DONE          E-Delivery
333         DONE          In Person
```

Answer (score 0):

Just chain the conditions:

```
select Id, 'DONE' as NewStatusType,
       (case when DaysTakenToReach >= 3 then 'USPS' 
             when StatusType = 'Consent' and SentDate is not null then 'E-Delivery'
             when StatusType = 'Consent' and SentDate is null then 'In Person'
        end) as DeliveryMethod
into #New
from DayCnt;
```

The problem with your logic is that the two `when` conditions are the same.  The first `StatusType = 'Consent'` matches so no subsequent conditions (in the first `case`) are considered.

EDIT:

If you want one row per `id`, then you need aggregation of some sort:

```
select Id, 'DONE' as NewStatusType,
       (case when max(DaysTakenToReach) >= 3 
             then 'USPS' 
             when sum(case when StatusType = 'Consent' and SentDate is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'E-Delivery'
             else 'In Person'
        end) as DeliveryMethod
into #New
from DayCnt
group by id;
```

Comment: This logic will still give me both **E-Delivery** and **USPS** values for Id = 1.
I want to populate `DeliveryMethod` depending on 2 conditions:
1. `DaysTakenToReach` greater than or equal to 3 and vice versa.
2. `StatusType` is **consent** and the `SentDate` is null or not null.

Comment: @NitinDeb . . . If you want one row per `id`, then you need some sort of aggregation or filtering.